# Two inner text boxes side by side within an outer box

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularray, tcbset

This code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[margin=1.2cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\scriptsize}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{varwidth}
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{colortbl}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage[]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                babel,
                calc,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shadings, shapes.geometric,
                3d}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc}
 \usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
 \tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse}
 \tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbset{
innenboxstyle/.style={
% Horizontale Aufteilung ===========
sidebyside adapt=right, % nein, sondern
% lefthand width=4cm, % entweder absolutes Maß
%lefthand ratio=0.65, % oder Verhältnis festlegen
% Farben und Schrift ===========
%lower separated=false,% kein Effekt, da eh weg
bicolor,colback=gray!10, colbacklower=white,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
fontupper=\scriptsize,
 sharpish corners, colframe=gray!20!black, colbacktitle=gray!40,coltitle=black,
scale=1.0, % besser die tikzpictures skalieren, statt die ganzen Boxen
% Alignment  ===========
sidebyside align=top seam, % vermutlich gewünscht
left=0mm, % Sonst Probleme mit dem halign lower, 
% der boxsep noch gibt einen zusätzlichen Defalult-Abstand
valign lower=center, 
halign lower=center, 
},
seitenboxstyle/.style={
sidebyside, 
sidebyside align=top seam, 
sidebyside gap=3mm,
sharpish corners,
lower separated=false,
colframe=gray!10!black,colback=white,fonttitle=\bfseries
% height fill, % grundsätzlich seiten-hoch % evtl. brauchbar
},
innenboxstylezwei/.style={
% Horizontale Aufteilung ===========
%sidebyside adapt=right, % nein, sondern
% lefthand width=4cm, % entweder absolutes Maß
%lefthand ratio=0.65, % oder Verhältnis festlegen
% Farben und Schrift ===========
%lower separated=false,% kein Effekt, da eh weg
bicolor,colback=gray!10, colbacklower=white,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
fontupper=\scriptsize,
 sharpish corners, colframe=gray!20!black, colbacktitle=gray!40,coltitle=black,
scale=1.0, % besser die tikzpictures skalieren, statt die ganzen Boxen
% Alignment  ===========
sidebyside align=top seam, % vermutlich gewünscht
left=0mm, % Sonst Probleme mit dem halign lower, 
% der boxsep noch gibt einen zusätzlichen Defalult-Abstand
valign lower=center, 
halign lower=center,
},
}

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\sffamily\scriptsize}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\scriptsize}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\seitentitelI{Title }%=========

\newcommand\titelVII{Subtitle}
\newcommand\textVII{\subsubsection*{Area}
\begin{equation*}
A=\frac{1}{2}\cdot g\cdot h
\end{equation*}}
\newcommand\bildVII{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.1, very thick, font=\footnotesize]%,cap=round,>=latex]
\coordinate [] (A) at (-0.6cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate [] (C) at (1.8cm,-1.0cm);
\coordinate [] (B) at (1cm,0.4cm);
\coordinate [label=right:h] (H) at (0.6cm,-0.4cm);
\draw[very thick] (A) -- node[sloped,above] {} (B) -- node[sloped,above,] {} (C) -- node[below] {g} (A);
\draw[dashed, thick] (B) -- (A-|B) ;

\end{tikzpicture}}
% =====================================
% =====================================
\newcommand*{\xdash}[1][3em]{\rule[0.5ex]{#1}{0.55pt}}

%-----------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[seitenboxstyle, title={\seitentitelI}]
\tcbsidebyside[innenboxstyle, title={\titelVII},]{\textVII}{\bildVII}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

generates an outer box with one inner box (Subtitle).

This code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                babel,
                calc,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shadings, shapes.geometric,
                3d}
\tikzset{baseline=(current bounding box.center),
    my angle/.style = {draw, font=\small, 
                       angle eccentricity=1.75, angle radius=3mm},
    base/.style = {draw, thick},
    dashline/.style = {densely dashed, very thick},
    every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right, inner sep=1pt, font=\small},
    Trapezium/.style = {base, trapezium,
                        trapezium left angle=60, trapezium right angle=120,
                        minimum width=30mm}
        }
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,Z} = 1pt, vline{1,Z} = 1pt,
             hline{even[3-X]} = {dashed, fg=gray, 0.5pt},
             colspec = {Q[l, bg=gray!10, font=\bfseries]
                        Q[l, bg=gray!10, mode=math, rightsep=24pt]
                        Q[c]},
             cell{even[2]}{2,3} = {r=2}{},
             row{1}  = {bg=gray!30},
             row{2-Z}= {rowsep  = 4pt}
             }
\SetCell[c=3]{l}    Drawing &   &   \\
Area    &   A=g\cdot h          &  
        \tikz{  \node (a) [Trapezium] {};
                \draw [dashline] (a.north west)  to["$h$" '] (a.south west);
                \path   (a.bottom left corner)  to["$g$"] (a.bottom right corner);
            }   \\   
        &   &   \\         
Circumference
        &   u=2\cdot a+2\cdot b &
        \tikz{  \node (a) [Trapezium] {};
                \path   (a.top left corner)  to["$a$" ] (a.bottom left corner)
                        (a.bottom left corner)  to["$b$"] (a.bottom right corner);;
            }   \\
        &   &   \\
\end{tblr}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

generates a further box, which is split via a tabular solution.
I would like to include this box to the outer box, next to the inner box "Subtitle" of the first code.
My attempts have failed so far.

It should look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=1.2cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                babel,
                calc,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shadings, shapes.geometric,
                3d}
\tikzset{baseline=(current bounding box.center),
    my angle/.style = {draw, font=\small,
                       angle eccentricity=1.75, angle radius=3mm},
    base/.style = {draw, thick},
    dashline/.style = {densely dashed, very thick},
    every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right, inner sep=1pt, font=\small},
    Trapezium/.style = {base, trapezium,
                        trapezium left angle=60, trapezium right angle=120,
                        minimum width=30mm}
        }
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{fonttitle=\Large\bfseries, coltitle=white, colback=white,
        colframe=cyan,nobeforeafter,
        sidebyside, sidebyside gap=3mm,
        lower separated=false
        }
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Title]
\begin{tblr}{%width=0.49\textwidth,
             hline{1,2,Z} = 1pt, vline{1,Z} = 1pt,
             hline{even[3-X]} = {dashed, fg=gray, 0.5pt},
             colspec = {Q[l, bg=gray!10, font=\bfseries]
                        Q[l, bg=gray!10, mode=math]
                        Q[c]},
             colsep  = 3pt,
             cell{even[2]}{2,3} = {r=2}{},
             row{1}  = {bg=gray!30},
             row{2-Z}= {rowsep  = 4pt}
             }
\SetCell[c=3]{l}    Drawing &   &   \\
Area    &   A=g\cdot h          &
        \tikz{  \node (a) [Trapezium] {};
                \draw [dashline] (a.north west)  to["$h$" '] (a.south west);
                \path   (a.bottom left corner)  to["$g$"] (a.bottom right corner);
            }   \\
        &   &   \\
Circumference
        &   u=2\cdot a+2\cdot b &
        \tikz{  \node (a) [Trapezium] {};
                \path   (a.top left corner)  to["$a$" ] (a.bottom left corner)
                        (a.bottom left corner)  to["$b$"] (a.bottom right corner);;
            }   \\
        &   &   \\
\end{tblr}
\tcblower                   % right side of box
\begin{tblr}{%width=0.49\textwidth,
             hline{1,2,Z} = 1pt, vline{1,Z} = 1pt,
             hline{even[3-X]} = {dashed, fg=gray, 0.5pt},
             colspec = {Q[l, bg=gray!10, font=\bfseries]
                        Q[l, bg=gray!10, mode=math]
                        Q[c]},
             colsep  = 3pt,
             cell{even[2]}{2,3} = {r=2}{},
             row{1}  = {bg=gray!30},
             row{2-Z}= {rowsep  = 4pt}
             }
\SetCell[c=3]{l}    Drawing &   &   \\
Area    &   A=g\cdot h          &
        \tikz{  \node (a) [Trapezium] {};
                \draw [dashline] (a.north west)  to["$h$" '] (a.south west);
                \path   (a.bottom left corner)  to["$g$"] (a.bottom right corner);
            }   \\
        &   &   \\
Circumference
        &   u=2\cdot a+2\cdot b &
        \tikz{  \node (a) [Trapezium] {};
                \path   (a.top left corner)  to["$a$" ] (a.bottom left corner)
                        (a.bottom left corner)  to["$b$"] (a.bottom right corner);;
            }   \\
        &   &   \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, but if I put more than two inner boxes in an outer box, the arrangement is a little bit confusing. I will complete my document and ask further questions in a new thread. Thank's, dear Zarko.